# AppSetting Data is visiblae in Controller but does not pass to View

Tags: asp.net-core

Fairly new to ASP.NET CORE so this could be a rookie mistake but it has be baffled!

I have been working on integrating a plugin for Square with some existing code, and when I write the data to console it's there but as soon as it's passed to the view I get a nullable error.

**Controller**

```
public IActionResult AccountPayments()
    {
        var appId = _config.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:ApplicationId");
        var locId = _config.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:LocationId");
        var env = _config.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:Environment");

        ModelState.Clear();

        var acc = new AccountPayment();
        acc.ApplicationId = appId;
        acc.LocationId = locId;
        acc.PaymentFormUrl = env;
        
        Console.WriteLine(acc.LocationId + " " + locId + " " + env);
        return View(acc);
     }
```

**View**

```
    @page
@model AccountPayment


@section Scripts {
    <!-- link to the SqPaymentForm library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Model.PaymentFormUrl"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.applicationId = "@Model.ApplicationId";
        window.locationId = "@Model.LocationId";
    </script>
    <!-- link to the local SqPaymentForm initialization -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/sq-payment-form.js"></script>
}
```

**Model**

```
namespace WebInvoice.Pages
{
    public class AccountPayment : PageModel
    {
        public string PaymentFormUrl { get; set; }
        public string ApplicationId { get; set; }
        public string LocationId { get; set; }

    }

}
```

When I remove the @model from the view it works OK.

When I check the console it displays the information.

When I run the application the view above returns the below error.

"System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'"

Eternally grateful to anyone who can shed some light on the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return View,don't add `@page` in your view,`@page` means it's a razor page rather than razor view.And also `PageModel` is used in razor page.You can refer to the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#razor-pages) about razor page.Here is a demo about mvc:

Model:

```
public class AccountPayment
    {
        public string PaymentFormUrl { get; set; }
        public string ApplicationId { get; set; }
        public string LocationId { get; set; }

    }
```

View(AccountPayment.cshtml):

```
@model AccountPayment


@section Scripts {
    <!-- link to the SqPaymentForm library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Model.PaymentFormUrl"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.applicationId = "@Model.ApplicationId";
        window.locationId = "@Model.LocationId";
    </script>
    <!-- link to the local SqPaymentForm initialization -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/sq-payment-form.js"></script>
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult AccountPayments()
    {
        var appId = _config.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:ApplicationId");
        var locId = _config.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:LocationId");
        var env = _config.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:Environment");

        ModelState.Clear();

        var acc = new AccountPayment();
        acc.ApplicationId = appId;
        acc.LocationId = locId;
        acc.PaymentFormUrl = env;
        
        Console.WriteLine(acc.LocationId + " " + locId + " " + env);
        return View(acc);
     }
```

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "AppSettings": {
    "ApplicationId": "123",
    "LocationId": "456",
    "Environment": "Development"
  }
}
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you Yiyi You, this has worked. Being new, I wasn't aware of the impact Razor View and Razor Pages could have when used incorrectly. 

I will definitely be looking into this further!